# How to insert degree Celsius symbol in node text in pgfplots/tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is my code.

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\selectcolormodel{gray}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=Voltage,ylabel=Current,title=IV Characteristics of PV Module]
\node[label={Set 1}] at (axis cs:2,60){};
\node[label=Set 2] at (axis cs:2,150){};
\node[label=Set 3] at (axis cs:2,240){};
\node[label=Set 4] at (axis cs:2,305){};
\addplot table [x=v1,y=i1, col sep=comma,mark=none] {SolarCellIV.csv};
\addplot table [x=v2,y=i2, col sep=comma,mark=none] {SolarCellIV.csv};
\addplot table [x=v3,y=i3, col sep=comma,mark=none] {SolarCellIV.csv};
\addplot table [x=v4,y=i4, col sep=comma,mark=none] {SolarCellIV.csv};
\node at (axis cs:12,360) {Set 1: 44.9 degreeCelsius};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I want the symbol for Degree Celsius in place of the text. How do I do so?

Comment: Pls include complete (`\begin document, \end document, \usepackage...`) otherwise we can't run your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use `\textdegree{}C`

Attention, you need to say `\usepackage{textcomp}` in your document's preamble.

Comment: Forces OP to give up initial aim of having "*no command layer between input and semantics*". See my [explanation of WYSIWYM vs WYSIWYG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471080/multilingual-document-with-math-scientific-symbols/471270?noredirect=1#comment1187884_471270)

Comment: @JonWong if having "no command layer between input and semantics" is your personal aim, don't use tex

Answer (score 23):

Here are two other options:

```
$44.9^\circ$C
\SI{44.9}{\celsius} % \usepackage{siunitx}
```

I prefer the second one (if siunitx is used anyway).

Comment: `\celsius` is enough for siunitx and you do not need math mode.

Comment: I liked the first one better. One less package to load helps speeding up execution times when you are dealing with big projects.

Comment: For those caring about consistency, there does not seem to be the equivalent `\fahrenheit` in siunitx. And, as with all units, your first solution probably needs an `\,` (half-space) between the number and unit

Answer (score 3):

Most is said already, but it's worth mentioning, that `$^\circ$` and `\textdegree{}` yield different symbols: [image: circ vs textdegree]

So either

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
44.9 \textcelsius{}
```

or

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\SI{44.9}{\celsius}
```

or if the exact typesetting is not important, this works as well:

```
$44.9\, ^\circ$C
```

If the curly brackets are omitted after `\textdegree{}` the space behind is ignored. \textdegree\ does the same job.

Answer (score 0):

similar to @sergej, for using the *siunitx* package,

I use `\SI{4.9}{\degreeCelsius}`

or you can also use `\usepackage{textcomp}` and `\textcelsius`

Answer (score 0):

I use the `amsmath` package and use it like this (replace `25` and `C` with whatever you need):

`$25^\text{o}C`

This is what it looks like:

```
25oC
```

I think it looks a lot like a real degree symbol, and it's fairly simple.