# How to write degrees into angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I have this code.

```
\draw(A)-- (X)-- (D)
pic["$\epsilon$"] {angle= A--X--D};
```

And it works perfectly. But I don't know how to display numbers. For example

```
\draw(A)-- (C)-- (D)
pic["$34$"] {angle= A--C--D};
```

and I get this

[image]

How to fix that? I mean how can I display the number (with degree symbol) like I did epsilon?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Write `\draw(A)-- (C)-- (D) pic["$34^\circ$"] {angle= A--C--D};` or similar. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258306/how-to-insert-degree-celsius-symbol-in-node-text-in-pgfplots-tikz for other variants.

Answer (score 2):

For show units is very appropriate use `siunitx` package and its macro `\ang{...}`:

```
\draw(A)-- (C)-- (D)
pic["\ang{34}"] {angle= A--C--D};
```

for nicer placement of angle you should define angle radius, for example:

```
\draw(A)-- (C)-- (D)
pic[angle radius=7mm,"\ang{34}"] {angle= A--C--D};
```