# What is the degree symbol?

Tags: typography, degrees

In order to have the following output involving the degree symbol

[image]

I can try

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
The angle is 30$^\circ$.
\end{document}
```

However, this is an awkward manner to obtain the degree symbol - one reverts to math mode and casts an existing symbol into superscript.

Is there a straightforward way of obtaining the degree symbol?

Comment: Have a look at [How to insert degree Celsius symbol in node text in pgfplots/tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258306/how-to-insert-degree-celsius-symbol-in-node-text-in-pgfplots-tikz)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `The angle is $30^\circ$.`, and the output is the same as `siunitx`'s.

Comment: I imagined something like `\degree`.

Comment: @AboAmmar: See my answer, `siunitx` does that for compatibility reasons. So if one strives for better looks then redefining them is best.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I would use [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and so a semantic command:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The angle is \ang{30}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can also load [`textcomp`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
The angle is 
30\textdegree.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you still use `\ang` if the  text was "The temperature is 30 deg C"?

Comment: @Viesturs: No. The meaning of `\ang` is angle, so I wouldn't misuse it for a temperature. I would use `\SI{30}{\celsius}`.

Comment: With your first example: I remember that `siunitx` uses the `$^\circ$` crutch for its degree symbols (for compatibility reasons), which I find often doesn't look very fitting to the font in use (too thin lines, too large circle). So I tend to redefine the appropriate `siunitx` symbol commands for my needs, usually the appropriate unicode character.

Comment: This does not make it less awkward. See my [explanation of WYSIWYM vs WYSIWYG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471080/multilingual-document-with-math-scientific-symbols/471270?noredirect=1#comment1187884_471270).

Comment: @JonWong You seem to need only a simple 1-1 relation between input and output. My needs are more complicated. In accessible document I want to tag such units and add alternative text in the pdf, in a children math book I want to color them, in a tabular I want to print the radians instead of the degree. In Libreoffice you would apply styles and then change them, LaTeX uses (more powerful) macros.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should add something like `This also works in math mode : $\alpha = \ang{30}$.`.

Answer (score 36):

The following example code serves to show that `siunitx` uses the ugly `$^\circ$` construction as well (for compatibility reasons). Most fonts have a degree symbol for angles (`U+00B0 DEGREE SIGN`) and some have a degree Celsius symbol for temperatures (`U+2103 DEGREE CELSIUS`, output by `\textcelsius` in my example) and these symbols usually would fit better to the line widths of the font.

My example also shows that the single degree symbol and the one included in the special degree Celsius glyph do not have to be the same, so I personally would redefine it accordingly when I'm using both in a piece of work, see the second line.

Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
°             % degree symbol
\si{\celsius} % ${}^{\circ}$
\textcelsius\ % special glyph of the font
\si{\degree}  % angle unit


\sisetup{
  math-celsius = °\text{C}, % for temperatures
  text-celsius = °C,
  math-degree = °, % for angles
  text-degree = °
}

°  
\si{\celsius} % now with the glyph
\textcelsius\ % special glyph of the font
\si{\degree}  % angle unit

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure how you measure 'most' fonts: classical TeX ones do not normally have a degree symbol. On degree Celsius, the single Unicode codepoint is a a compatibility character, and decomposes to 'degree' + 'letter C'.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I wrote from experience of non-TeX fonts, that all of the ones I've come across have the ° (degree) symbol. With the degree Celsius, the second line in my example compares `°` + `C` with the single glyph, and they look different (with the CM font, haven't tested other ones). These are just my conclusions, I'm not an expert on this.

Answer (score 32):

There is also a [`gensymb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gensymb) package. I prefer it, since it provides just a symbol for both text/math modes, and you can do everything what you want with it.

Example:

```
\usepackage{gensymb}
% ...
$20 \degree$
```

Comment: I love this simple and practical answer!

Answer (score 11):

The symbol is U+00B0 in Unicode, and the TS1 encoding contains it if you want to use legacy NFSS.  The standard command for it is `\textdegree` and is defined by either `textcomp` or `fontspec`.  You can also enter it in your UTF-8 source file, or use `inputenc` to declare a different input encoding.  Virtually all text fonts support it.

Example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % For TS1.
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\begin{document}
30\textdegree{} is hot.

20\textdegree{} is pleasing.

10\textdegree{} is not.

0\textdegree{} is freezing.
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample image]

There is also `\textcelsius` for the character ℃ (U+2103), but (as of the last time I checked) to get PDFLaTeX to recognize the UTF-8 character on input, you must add the command `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{"2103}{\textcelsius}`.

Comment: In current versions of LaTeX, it is no longer necessary to load `textcomp`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `°` directly with

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}    

I love 25 °C in my room

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled]

Comment: Actually `textcomp` is enough. Since 2018 `utf8` is the predefined input encoding, and you'll find `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\textdegree}` in `utf8enc.dfu`. AFAIK nowadays there is basically no use for `gensymb`.

Comment: Ups, edited, good

Comment: How to type on the keyboard the ° symbol?

Comment: depends on the layout of your keyboard, you can insert by `Alt`+ `248`, if you have USA International keyboard `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `ALT` + `;`  | Best in Latam Keyboard `SHIFT` + `\``

Comment: On a Mac you use `command` + `control` + `space` and just search for degree glyph.

Answer (score 2):

Using `^\circ` is poor solution used in old days. Today, we have Unicode fonts. Almost all Unicode font supports the `°` character. You can use it directly. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

I love 22\,°C in my room.

{\bf I love 22\,°C in my room.}

\bye
```

If you have complicated access to this character with your keyboard, you can define a macro for this. It is usual in TeX. For example

```
\fontfam[lm]
\def\deg{°}

I love 22\,\deg C in my room.

{\bf I love 22\,\deg C in my room.}

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a fairly short and simple solution, without using additional and/or special packages for that purpose. In the preamble define the following:
`\renewcommand{\deg}{$^\circ$}`

As `\deg` is a reserved word, it must be redefined for this purpose. In my usage, I have not yet seen any obstacle to do that.

Later, in the text, you can simply type `The angle is 30\deg.`

Comment: No, I don't think `\deg` (which is an function symbol) should be redefined for this. Your command will fail within math mode as well... The preferred way nowadays should be `siunitx`. Besides all, your proposition has been done by the O.P. already, apart from wrapping it up in a macro.

Comment: Generally `\circ` maps to U+2218 (Ring Operator), whereas the degree sign is U+00B0 (Degree Sign). In some fonts, using `^\circ` can give a very small circle that is barely noticable, e.g. when using Fira Sans Math font.