# Diagnosing Standalone and Gensymb conflict

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, standalone

Disclaimer: I am new-ish to LaTeX, and self-taught.

I am trying to make a "Unit Circle" TikZ graphic, in which I would like to have the `\degree` symbol from the `gensymb` package in the label text of a node.

My current workflow involves the `standalone` package, and uses the `\include` command to create a sort of "master file" containing each of my creations on its own page which I reference in other Overleaf projects using the 'output file from another project' and the `graphicx` package to reduce compile time. There is probably a better way to do this, but it keeps it simple enough for me and I like having everything in more or less the same place so I can make quick references between my images. It has worked so far, until now...

My problem is, it is preferable if I don't have to update the preamble of my master document every time I add a new picture, especially since that's where I define things like colors which occasionally use identical names (e.g. gradient1). Hence, I load `\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}` to read the preamble of each standalone separately. Again, this has worked well enough so far that I have been able to solve any hiccups myself.

I have failed to diagnose why exactly, but there is something going on with the `[subpreambles]` tag and loading the `gensymb` package. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb} % for degree symbol

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {$0\degree$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which I have in Overleaf as `degree-test.tex`. When I try to reference this file in another:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \include{degree-test}
\end{document}
```

I get the error: `Package standalone Warning: Sub-preamble of file 'degree-test.tex' has changed. Content will be ignored. Please rerun LaTeX! on input line 4.`

I compile with LuaLaTeX, but other compilers produce similar results. Even removing `\degree` from the node label produces the error, despite not actually using the symbol. There must be some kind of conflict with commands which define certain things during the preamble, but I don't know how to read the error logs and they're very frightening on the surface.

Is there a simple fix for this?

EDIT: I have also disqualified `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` and `\include` vs `\includestandalone` as culprits.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

So, according to user @Davislor on [this TeX.SE forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384873/what-is-the-degree-symbol), I can remove the package `gensymb` and simply use `\textdegree` which is a part of modern LaTeX distributions. It does not work in math mode, which is unfortunate, but for my application this is begrudgingly acceptable. Using `$\textrm{\textdegree}$` is fine.

For those curious, the `\ang{}` provided by the `siunitx` package looks too empty for my taste, which as demonstrated in the post linked above is the same as `^\circ`.